# Multiselect Drop down with optgroup

Tags: sapui5

How achieve multiselect drop down in openui5 with optgroup. Something like this where in I can select elements both in child and parent level. My json data is something like this :

```
{
Group1: {
 OptionValue : "Option1",
 OptionValue : "Option2",
 OptionValue : "Option3"
},
Group2:{
 OptionValue : "Option3",
 OptionValue : "Option4",
}
}
```

Screenshot of the desired output:

[image]

How to achieve multi select dropdown with optgroups in openui5. Referred from [this example](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/) .

Existing [sample](http://jsbin.com/OGAQUDo/1/edit?html,output) of dropdown that I am trying to bind is added. I have tried several combinations but unable to get it correct.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Added a link for the way I am trying unable to find proper way to bind to get the desired output .

Comment: `MultiComboBox` now supports grouping of options. See https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.MultiComboBox/sample/sap.m.sample.MultiComboBoxGrouping. Selecting a whole group isn't yet supported. Try asking for such enhancement on Github

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any Control that has the exact behavior you describe, but there are some that you could have a closer look at:

The [MultiComboBox](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.MultiComboBox/samples) is a dropdown with multi selection, but doesn't seem to have grouping.

To have multi selection and grouping, you could consider a [Dialog](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Dialog/samples) with a [grouped List](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListGrouping/preview) which allows [multiple selections](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListSelection/preview).
There is a [SelectDialog](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.SelectDialog/samples) Control that you can configure to include all those features.
After selection, you could use a [MultiInput](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.MultiInput/samples) to show the selected values in a tag-like design.

Comment: All links mentioned in answer are down.

Comment: Sorry, I used SAP internal links by mistake. Should be fixed now.